# Facebook Graph API doesn't "login" the way it should

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Facebook's Graph API.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I can't seem to get the login_url() to work correctly.

I'm requiring the Facebook SDK correctly (definitely)

Underneath my require I have this:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
```

Those should be enough for just logging a user in.

Next I set the default app with the correct APP ID and APP Secret (Hidden for obvious reasons)

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxx', 'yyyy');
```

I create my helper for my facebook login and set the redirect URL (site hidden for my privacy)

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://siteurl.com/dashboard');
```

Dashboard refers to the index.php?a=dashboard (htaccess rewrite rules)

I try to set the $session variable from the redirect (the get parameter 'code' does exist, however, I do not get redirected to Facebook to approve the app)

```
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
     echo $ex;
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

No exceptions are outputted.

My IF statement to check whether or not the session exists, the else statement is always called.

```
if ($session) {
  echo 'test';
} else {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    ?>
    <a href="<?=$loginUrl;?>"><img src="/images/fb-login.png"></a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I have tried this with both my live app and the test version of my app.

I hope I haven't duplicated an existing thread because I did do a general search.

Please feel free to ask me any questions and thank you for taking the time to assist me.

Comment: shouldn't it be `"<?echo $loginUrl;?>"` instead of `"<?=$loginUrl;?>"`?

Comment: @Alon They do the same thing? It's just shorthand...

Comment: Not sure, that's why I put it in comment and not as answer